# find coordinates of color in RGB image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am trying to find the coordinates that in RGB images, then use these coordinates to train my neural network model
i am running the below code but i am not getting any output.. any idea why? do you have a better idea to get the coordinates of green color from RGB images? 
Please advise,

UPDATE : attached image is one of my training data images

```
color = (0,255,0) #green value in RGB
for image in train_data[0:5000]:
  img = Image.open(image)
  rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
  for x in range(rgb_im.size[0]):
    for y in range(rgb_im.size[1]):
      r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
      if (r,g,b) == color:
        print(f"Found {color} at {x},{y}!")
```

[![Image Examples][1]][1]

Comment: Are you sure your image has a pure green pixel in it?

Comment: have you tried with a pixel you are sure you have to see if it finds it?

Comment: @Craig 100 percent, i updated with an image example

Comment: @LiorCohen thats what my code suppose to be doing

Comment: print some of your (r,g,b) to see if it is indeed in the form you are expecting. i.e tuple with three integers between 0 and 255.

Comment: @LiorCohen done, and working fine , only this scope of code is taking time to load but there is no output

Comment: can you show the output of rgb_im.getpixel((10,10)) of your first image

Comment: you can convert image to numpy array and use numpy function which should works faster and you don't have to use `for`-loop to find all items. Module `cv2` has function to find pixel with colors in some range so it is better when green may have small different in values.

Comment: [1]: https://imgur.com/LGedqjN 
check the above link, do u think the value of green is 203? @LiorCohen

Comment: @furas can u provide a link for the function please?

Comment: now try to run your code for color = (178, 203, 225), does it find this pixel?

Comment: @LiorCohen fantastic, and the output is
Found (178, 203, 225) at 10,10!
Found (178, 203, 225) at 770,9!
Found (178, 203, 225) at 10,10!

Comment: `arr = numpy.array(img)` and later you can use `arr == color` to compare all pixels with color but it give True/False and you need other function (which I don't remeber right now) to convert it to coordinates.

Comment: put the conversation summary as answer for the future readers

Comment: @LiorCohen will definitely do, but one last question before i mark it as solved, is the green value in this case will be(0, 203, 0) ?

Comment: I do not know what you call green in your image. open your image with any image viewer, go to some pixel you call green and see. pure green should be (0, 255, 0) in RGB space but your images apparently does not have such.

Comment: @LiorCohen thank you, appreciate ur help :)

Comment: This is a standard image processing question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `neural-network` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the comments correspondence above, your code seems to be working fine but the input color (0, 255, 0) is indeed not exist in the image.